# php:7.0-apache container cannot be build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my Dockerfile I have this:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install procps less
```

and on Friday it worked properly. Today I have this strange error:

```
#86 1.116 CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                       81  B/s |  38  B     00:00
#86 1.118 Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926799/centos-through-vm-no-urls-in-mirrorlist

That base image you start from uses CentOS Linux 8, which reached EOL as of 31st Dec 2021, but they left the repositories for 1 month longer, until 31st Jan 2022: https://www.centos.org/centos-linux-eol/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Centos through VM - no URLs in mirrorlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926799/centos-through-vm-no-urls-in-mirrorlist)

Comment: @froblesmartin I've seen this question already but unfortunately sed commands didn't help.

Comment: Check this answer I have given at another question which is open: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70938559/7653022