# Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist

Tags: docker, centos, devops, yum

I am trying to download java using yum on centOs which I specified in a Dockerfile.
After pulling centOs image the run crashed and threw this error!?
also to mention that my server instance is AWS EC2!

```
Step 2/9 : RUN yum install java -y
 ---> Running in 39fc233aa965
CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                      184  B/s |  38  B     00:00
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist
The command '/bin/sh -c yum install java -y' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Centos through VM - no URLs in mirrorlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926799/centos-through-vm-no-urls-in-mirrorlist). The [top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70964301/3025856) below suggests that this (now closed) question includes an answer to this question.

Answer (score 185):

Try editing your dockerfile

```
FROM centos

RUN cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
RUN sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*

RUN yum -y install java

CMD /bin/bash
```

Refer to this code

[failed-metadata-repo-appstream-centos-8](https://techglimpse.com/failed-metadata-repo-appstream-centos-8/)

Comment: Awesome! this fixed my issue. Its good to know centos maintains vaults of it's older versions

Comment: the link provided fixed my problem. I was not using docker.

Comment: This link worked for me! Thanks a lot for saving time :)

Comment: Worked as well for Dockerfile Centos based image on WSL

Comment: You don't need the `cd` command. Even if it's there it's inconsequential. Because when the next command RUN command is executed a new 'layer' is created and whatever the cd did is gone.

Answer (score 78):

If you don't already have it, you'll need the gpg keys:

```
wget 'http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/centos-gpg-keys-8-3.el8.noarch.rpm'
sudo rpm -i 'centos-gpg-keys-8-3.el8.noarch.rpm'
```

Then it's as simple as transitioning like so:

```
dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo=extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos
```

Don't worry -- it doesn't remove any repos, it simply temporarily ignores all of yours, and downloads information regarding the new mirrors.

You may at this point want to actually upgrade your packages:

```
sudo dnf distro-sync
```

You'll now be able to use "yum" as usual.

Comment: One first has to remove all packages from the `PowerTools` repository before `distro-sync`, which are being duplicated. Some of `mirror.centos.org` seems to be `vault.centos.org` (archived) now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I hit this error when trying to download wget to the base centos-8 image. @BigCat's suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 78):

Go to `/etc/yum.repos.d/`

```sh
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
```

Run

```sh
sudo sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sudo sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sudo yum update -y
```

Then do what you want

Comment: Same answer given  in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71586270

Comment: The only answer that really helped for imported Docker image (Centos) in WSL2.

Comment: Excellent. This should be the answer for most people. (Not using Docker.)

Comment: This answer is taken from my answer, which I wrote 1 month earlier!!! stackoverflow.com/a/71586270

Comment: Using '^' ensures the '#' is added only once and only at the beginning of the line:
sudo sed -i 's/^mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*

Answer (score 23):

CentOS 8 reached EOL on 2021-12-31 ([announcement](https://www.centos.org/centos-linux-eol/)).

Therefore, the URLs to the mirrors don't work anymore. Instead of using `sed` to modify the URLs to point to the archived mirrors, CentOS [officially recommends](https://centos.org/centos-stream/#centos-stream-8) to convert from CentOS Linux 8 to CentOS Stream 8 via:

```
dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos
dnf distro-sync
```

After that, `dnf`/`yum` will work again.

Comment: better example please

Comment: It is not just an example, execute the commands as they are. If you are not root, prefix them with `sudo`. If you need them in a docker file, prefix them with `RUN`.

Answer (score 17):

I tried to use CentOS 8 with wsl and got the same error. Steps to fix the problem (as root):

```
# sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
# sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
# dnf distro-sync
# dnf -y install java
```

The top voted answer did not work for me (by @Hashbrown). The answer with Dockerfile was not for my case either.

Comment: I think "dnf distro-sync" will undo the changes made by the 2 prior sed commands

Comment: dnf does not change its configuration under /etc . Checkout **man dnf**. It just upgrades, downgrades or keeps selected installed packages to match the latest version available from any enabled repository.

Comment: And yet, after the "dnf distro-sync" finishes running, entering 
grep "baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org" /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
shows what it would show before the 2nd sed command.
https://pastebin.com/PBbwES3A
If we skip the "dnf distro-sync" command, java will install.

Comment: Here's the full output generated by dnf distro-sync
https://pastebin.com/mMZkkbCL
note the changes to /etc starting at line 1476

Comment: Using '^' ensures the '#' is added only once and only at the beginning of the line:
sudo sed -i 's/^mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*

Answer (score 15):

Use these commands to update centOS8.0 on AWS EC2:

```
sudo sed -i -e "s|mirrorlist=|#mirrorlist=|g" \
    -e "s|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g" \
        /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

FROM centos

```
RUN cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
RUN sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*

RUN yum -y install java

CMD /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your docker file with below. It should work.

```
    RUN  sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
    RUN  sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
    RUN yum update -y
```

Answer (score 1):

Mine had to be a mixture of some of the other answers. I used latest (as of a couple days ago) CentOS with Docker default image. (**sudo** failed as I was already in **root**)

```
sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
yum install PACKAGE
```

no update of yum was needed

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the below-mentioned steps:**

1. Go to the ***/etc/yum.repos.d/*** directory.

   cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
2. Run the below commands to hash the mirror-list in all yum.repos.d files then replace the existed Baseurl with the **vault.centos.org**

   sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
   sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
3. Then run yum update or install any package you want

   yum update -y

Answer (score -1):

Go to `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory. Open `.repo` file and manually edit mirrorlist from `$releasever` to `8-stream`.

For example : /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux-BaseOS.repo

1. open file in vi

   `sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux-BaseOS.repo`
2. comment `mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=BaseOS&infra=$infra`

   `#mirrorlist=http://......`
3. within vi, copy paste `mirrorlist=http://......` line

   `yy and p`
4. uncomment and edit the copied line by replacing $releasever to 8-stream

   `mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8-stream&arch=$basearch&repo=BaseOS&infra=$infra`
5. save and exit vi

   `:wq`

Repeat above 5-steps for other .repo files.